# How do I provide method parameter info from a Language Server?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

I am trying to implement a language server for visual studio code for a language whose method calling is similar to JavaScript (method name plus parameters inside parenthesis).

I would like to provide parameter info (name and type) after the user typed a method and parenthesis based on the position of the cursor inside the parenthesis. For example, when coding in Typescript in vscode, if I type:

```
Math.pow(
```

I get a tooltip showing the signature of the method and the first parameter name and type in bold:

[image: first parameter tooltip]

then when I enter the first parameter and enter a comma, the tooltip offers details about the second parameter:

[image: second parameter tooltip]

I was able to find a way to provide autocompletion on the name of the method, but not the behavior described above for the parameters. Is there an example or a tutorial on how to prompt that tooltip from a language server extension in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: In addition to the example implementation given, there is also minimal documentation in the [Language Extension Guidelines](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/language-support#_help-with-function-and-method-signatures) and in the [vscode namespace API](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an example in [the official php extension source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/extensions/php/src/features/signatureHelpProvider.ts). I just had to implement a SignatureHelpProvider.